# How to focus an input element as soon as it is enabled?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css

I am enabling a text field on click of a button. After onblur event on that input text, I want that it should be hidden. Now in the case when button is clicked and input field is shown, without changing any value inn that field, I am clicking away outside. But that field is not getting hidden, because the onblur event never fired from that field as I never touched it after enabling. Hence I want that as soon as the field is enabled, the focus should be on that input element.

Something as :

[image]

As against :

[image]

> Note: This is in reference with a cell of inline edit type of SLDS-table

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set the focus by using `.focus` method in the button click function. Check this fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/27nobjku/) I have created.

```
document.getElementById("myAnchor").focus();
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but its not working. I tried giving slds-has-focus class to std lightning componnents by default, but its still not working. Does this class doesn't apply to std lightning components